# How to update data in a mysql table

Tags: mysql, sql

i was considering about how can i implement this functionality:

Imagine table named "Web", where is being stored as:

```
| id | center 
|:---- |:------
| 1  | pepe  
| 2  | juan  
| 3  | rosa
```

What i want to do is update first the register 1 with carlos:

```
| id | center 
|:---- |:------
| 1  | carlos
| 2  | juan  
| 3  | rosa
```

After that, ill do the same with register 2 with luis:

```
| 1  | carlos
| 2  | luis  
| 3  | rosa
```

And this continuous..

How can be implemented in mysql?

Thank you all

---

The problem is that the table will contain 150 registers, and when a counter is equal to 150, i want to start updating the table with new data starting from first register, after 5 seconds for instance, update the second register... so on until the 150.

Comment: `UPDATE table SET center='carlos' WHERE id=1`?

Answer (score 1):

You could use a `join` with a derived table that defines the values:

```
update web w join
       (select 1 as id, 'carlos' as center union all
        select 2 as id, 'luis' as center
       ) x
       using (id)
    set w.center = x.center;
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple SQL `UPDATE` statements will perform the change you want.

> What i want to do is update first the register 1 with carlos:

```
update center = 'carlos' where id = 1;
```

> After that, ill do the same with register 2 with luis:

```
update center = 'luis' where id = 2;
```